# Reactive update of a function in an #each cycle in Svelte

Tags: svelte

I have separate arrays for headers and data of a table. And want to add sort order icons for the header (`Headers` array). Sort order is stored separately (`sorting` array).

```html
{#each data.Header as h, i}
    <th class="text-start" on:click={()=>headClick(i)}><Icon name={sortOrderIcon(i)}/> {h}</th>
{/each}
```

How make Svelte to refresh this cycle on the `sorting` array change.

```js
function headClick(i){
    let s=_.find(sorting, o => o.col===i)
    if (_.isUndefined(s)){ 
        sorting.push({col: i, sort: 'asc'})
        return
    }
    if (s[i].sort==='asc'){ 
        s[i].sort='desc'
    }
    else { 
        _.remove(sorting, (o)=>o.col===i)
    }
}
```

Comment: paste your `headClick` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactivity is triggered by assignment. If `sorting` is used to reactively update the rows, you should overwrite that or use dummy assignments, e.g.

```js
function headClick(i) {
    const s = sorting.find(o => o.col === i);
    if (s == null) {
        // spread instead of push
        sorting = [...sorting, { col: i, sort: 'asc' }];
        return;
    }
    if (s[i].sort === 'asc') { 
        s[i].sort = 'desc';
        sorting = sorting; // dummy assignment
    }
    else {
        // assignment with filter instead of remove
        sorting = sorting.filter(o => o.col !== i);
    }
}
```

To make the icon update which has a dependency on `sorting`, define the function itself reactively:

```js
$: sortOrderIcon = i => {
    ...
};
```

If `sorting` appears within the function, it will automatically be redefined and called again.